# Ways to share a variable among threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have a general question about parallel programming in C and C++ and would appreciate it if you could answer it. As far as I know, we can declare a variable in at least one level higher (parent thread) to share it among children threads. So, I was wondering if there is any other way to share a variable among threads with the same parent thread? Is this API dependant or not?

Comment: You can also trade information cross threads via a [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) system, these informations could very well be a value or the address of the variable you want to share

Comment: the two main issues here are: a. is the "shared" variable going to be written to?   b. is it critical?  I can just define a global, init it before starting my threads and use it as a read-only (bad design, but works). Alternatively, if I do update it, and the value in the other threads isnt critical (e.g. I use it only as a debug viewer), I can again use it similarly. If it is critical and needs changing, there is an issue - C++ memory model (or lack of it). See Basile's answer for each version/implementation.

Comment: I was more looking for the place where the shared data (variable) can be declared. It must be at least one level higher than the threads that want to share it, no matter which parallel programming API is being used. Right?

Comment: @user3684042 Wrong, it doesn't matter "when" it was created since there is only one memory shared across threads (unlike processes fork), it if it exists at some point you can access it after that point as long as it is not destroyed yet. (This doesn't take into consideration Thread local storage :)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Posix threads, read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

For [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11), read the documentation of its [thread library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread)

All [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) of the same [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) share the *same* [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). As commented by [Marco A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1938163/marco-a) consider also [thread_local](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) variables.

Notice that you share data or [memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) (not variables, which exist only in the source code)

In practice, you'll better protect with a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex) the shared data (for synchronization) to avoid [data races](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

In the simple case, the mutex and the shared data are in some global variables.

You could also use [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) operations.

BTW, you could also develop a parallel application using some [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) paradigm, e.g. using [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) (or simply using some RPC or other messages, e.g. JSON on sockets). You might consider for regular numerical applications to use the GPGPU e.g. using [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/). And of course you might mix all the approaches (using *OpenCL*, with several *threads*, and having your parallel software running in several such processes communicating with MPI).

Debugging a heavily parallel software can become a nightmare. Performance may depend upon the hardware system and may require tricky tuning. [scalability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) and [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) may becoming a growing concern.[map-reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) is often a useful model.

Comment: Might also be related: [thread_local](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) (TLS standard enforced)

Comment: I was more looking for the place where the shared data (variable) can be declared. It must be at least one level higher than the threads that want to share it, no matter which parallel programming API is being used. Right?

Comment: A *variable* is something textual in the source code. What matters is memory location. (think of local variables in recursive functions to see the difference).

Answer (score 6):

In C++ and C any memory location (identified by a variable) can be shared among threads. The memory space is the same across all threads. There is no parent/child thread relationship with memory.

The challenge is to control or synchronize access to the memory location among the threads.

That is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Any global variable is sharable among threads, since threads are light weight processes sharing the same address space. For synchronization, you need to ensure mutual exclusion while updating/accessing those global variables through semaphores or wait notify blocks.